# When will I get Android 4.4 KitKat update on Nexus 4 in Romania?

Tags: nexus-4, ota-update, 4.4-kitkat

I am in a bit of worry because I own a Nexus 4 device, and I noticed many articles on the web stating that an OTA update to 4.4 is out but I didn't receive any notification on my device. Also, when I check for updates, the update is not showing up.

Should I be concerned about this, or does it just takes more time for the update to get to me? I am in Romania.

**UPDATE**

For those of you who are really eager to install the new update you can check up this link: It's still an OTA, nothing will be wiped on your device and the update files are the official ones provided by Google!

Link: http://phandroid.com/2013/11/21/download-the-nexus-4s-android-4-4-kitkat-krt16s-ota-directly-from-google/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to wait. It will eventually come.

If you read the [Checking for updates won't get you KitKat faster, says Google employee](http://androidandme.com/2013/11/news/checking-for-updates-wont-get-you-kitkat-faster-says-google-employee/) article, it says:

> According to Dan, the updates are first sent out to 1 percent of
>   devices. If it goes smoothly, it is sent to 25, 50, and 100 percent of
>   users over what he says is “a week or two.” So if you’re waiting for
>   that update, quit mashing that update button and regulate yourself to
>   around once a day.

Comment: low reputation stopped me from doing this already:)